# Adding TextFields with Commas Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to add the values in two textfields. When value is inputed into both and a button is pressed to add it, the text fields are formatted to have commas:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        carPriceField1.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: [formatter numberFromString:carPriceField1.text]];
```

so then if you click the button again, the commas are still inside of the textfield. So the calculation ignores all the numbers after the comma.
for example, if it were to add 20,000 and 30,000 the answer would be 50.

How can I add these numbers with commas? Do I have to reformat, and then add?

Comment: not sure if i understand correctly. but why dont you keep the operations in a different internal variable? like treat them as numbers only behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter` is not intended to be used this way. In Interface Builder just drag a Number Formatter onto the text field you want to be formatted with commas. Then it will format the text it displays in the text field according to the settings you provide in Interface Builder. When you want to retrieve the numerical value just get it as follows for example if you want integers:

```
int carPrice = [carPriceField1 intValue];
```

Comment: where is the number formatter that you have to drag from interface builder?